# "You will die" vs "You shall die?"

Tags: connotation

Had a discussion about the difference of connotation between "You shall" and "You will"; after discussion I became curious about which would be more appropriate in the context below.

**The Context:**

> There's a man, named John, who is, as a mortal, going to die someday, and another man, an ardent some-pseudo-religion believer, who knocked on John's door to offer the religion of his. However, the fanatic was refused and said "but remember. You will/shall die someday," calmly like a soft breeze.

**My question is:**

If the fanatic had said *shall*, would it have been as if he was implying that John was inevitably going to die, no matter his will would be; that "you'd better believe God"--with some offence hidden under *shall?*

And if he'd said *will*, would it have been as if he was reminding John of the fact that John was going to die; that "it's the best for you to believe God"--with no offence?

And what if the fanatic had been just a normal religious man who casually came to offer the religion, then what would've been more likely for him to say? *Shall* or *will?* Or would either of them have been too offensive to say someone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The will/shall distinction is both vague and controversial but the general consensus is that *shall* indicates intent, obligation, or duty, while *will* refers to simple futurity.

To anyone who subscribes to this dichotomy, the sentence "You will die" is an unarguable observation about human mortality, but "You shall die" is nothing less than a threat.

**Edit** I have heard people prescribe *shall* for first person and *will* for second and third, but I have never, ever heard anyone following that recommendation.  Ditto with using "will" to mean intent for first person.

In the song "We Shall Overcome", the singers are announcing their resolve, not smugly predicting victory.  My favorite line in *The Devil Wore Prada*, a movie full of witty lines, comes from this exchange.

> Andy: Wish me luck!
>
> Emily: No. Shan't.

I am going to use that line at some point.  "Have a good day!"  "No. Shan't."

Comment: However -- for completeness -- note that in the first person, the imputation is reversed. *I/We will* implies intent or desire; *I/We shall* implies futurity.

Comment: I thought that old will/shall reversal for first person was dead and buried. Ought to be.

Comment: Amazing (if this answer is correct). The meanings have nearly reversed since Shakespeare's day (where I believe *will* conveyed intent, and *shall* conveyed obligation, but also was used for simple futurity).

Comment: (Following the edit) I know people -- British, admittedly, and in their eighties -- who really do differentiate between *will* and *shall,* and *would* and *should* similarly. It's endearingly quaint.

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct. Doesn't "will" traditionally imply some kind of agency? "You shall die" is the correct form if it is intended as a threat, but wouldn't it also work to emphasize the inevitability of the event?

Answer (score -1):

I think you'll find that shall is considered archaic in North America. Apparently, however, the Brits still maintain a distinction between the two by using "shall" referring to a future occurrence when using the first person (I, we).

***We shall arrive in Scotland at 3:40 p.m. tomorrow***

When using the second or third person (you, he, she, they), the word of preference is will:

***They will arrive in Scotland tomorrow afternoon.***

Much too complex for North Americans. Well, except for lawyers. In their speak a difference exists between the two, but apparently lawyers always screw it up. "Will" is a contractual agreement that party A will, at a future time, do something. "Shall, on the other hand, means "has a duty to... at a future time." Ask your lawyers; I have no clue what the difference is (Oh, wait, history says they probably won't know either).

Comment: See my previous comment.  I'll bet 99% of BrE speakers have no idea about this  -  it's strictly for old-fashioned grammarians.